# Ubuntu startup file location

Tags: ubuntu, boot, upstart

Ubuntu does not use the inittab file any longer so where can one find the set of files that ubuntu executes on start after the init process is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com). The related files are in `/etc/init` and `/etc/init.d`.